# Split data.frame rows and shuffle their order

Tags: r, dataframe, split, shuffle

I have a `data.frame` such as this:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = c("A","B;C","D","E","F;G;H","I"), val1 = rnorm(6), val2 = letters[1:6], stringsAsFactors=F)
```

There is an `id` column which some of its values have a semicolon indicating it combines several `id`s, and their values in the rest of the columns are shared.

For each row with an id with a semicolon:

1. I would like to split the `id` by the semicolon separator
2. replicate that `data.frame` row by the number of `id`s that were split
3. randomly `shuffle` the order of the replicated `data.frame`
4. replace the original row in `df` with the one I created in 3, such that the order of all other rows in `df` is unchanged.

Here's my cumbersome attempt:

```
idx <- which(grepl(";",df$id))
l <- lapply(idx, function(i){
  ids <- strsplit(df$id[i], split = ";")[[1]]
  df.i <- do.call("rbind", replicate(length(ids), df[i,,drop=F], simplify = FALSE))
  df.i$id <- ids[permute::shuffle(ids)]
  return(df.i)
})

idx.names <- df$id[idx]

for(i in 1:length(idx.names)){
  df <- rbind(df[1:(which(df$id == idx.names[i])-1),,drop=F],
              l[[i]],
              df[(which(df$id == idx.names[i])+1):nrow(df),,drop=F])
}
```

So I'm looking for something more elegant (perhaps using `tidyverse` or `data.table`) and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows`, then grouped by 'val2', `sample` the `row_number()` in `slice`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   separate_rows(id) %>%
   group_by(val2) %>%
   slice(sample(row_number()))
```